# How to insert additional columns within method in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Here is an example,
Basically this is third party API wrapper.

```
class Todo::Add
  attr_reader :todo, :todo_name

  def self.call(*args)
    new(*args).call
  end

  def initialize(todo)
    @todo = todo
    @todo_name = todo.name
  end

  def call
    detail = external_todo_service.create(
      name: todo_name
    )

    # do something ...

  rescue TodoServiceError => e
    list.errors[:base] << e.message
    list
  end
end
```

And We can call this with something like `Todo::Add.call(OBJECT)`.

However what if I'd love to add some `description` parameter to third party api request optionally.
How can I add it efficiently as an option?

`Todo::Add.call(OBJECT, description: 'some detail for todo')`

```
  def call
    detail = external_todo_service.create(
      name: todo_name
      description: description
    )

    # do something ...

  rescue TodoServiceError => e
    list.errors[:base] << e.message
    list
  end
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
When I call this method without `description` parameter, external_todo_service.create() `description` parameter is going to be removed as well ideally.

Answer (score 0):

Given your code, the most logical would be to extend the `Todo` class with a new attribute (description) and use it in the `call` implementation. Also, i wouldnt store `todo` instance attributes (like `todo_name`) in the beginning:

```
  def initialize(todo)
    @todo = todo
  end

 def call
    detail = external_todo_service.create(
      name: @todo.name,
      description: @todo.description
    )
    ...
  end
```

Your question is very broad though. It really depends on how your client code will use the functionality, how the third party service works, etc.pp.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So how can I code when I need the external_todo_service.create doesn't take `description`. I'd love to make it optionally. In the example, description doesn't belong to `todo` object.

Comment: `Todo::Add.call(OBJECT, description: 'some detail for todo')`

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by your code.  I associate call like this:
[Ruby class definition (call)](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html#method-i-call)

In other words, as far as I know, call isn't something you implement, it invokes the method that precedes it, passing in variables.

If my understanding is correct, your call probably invokes the initialize method on your class.  Which means you should be able to do something like this:

```
def initialize(todo, params)
   @todo = todo
   @todo_name = todo.name
   @description = params[:description]
end
```

In theory you can delete the method implementation of call on the class since it's a reserved ruby method and you would be overwriting it which might be bad.

And it might be more legible if you wrote the code like this:

```
Todo::Add.new(OBJECT, description: 'some detail for todo')
```